# Return a textbox to defaultvalue if the textbox is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a text box for searching.  For some reason, .blur() will not work on my computer. I created a test file to test it, and it still won't work:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Demo</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#search').blur(function() {
        alert('hello');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="search" value="hello" type="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you should attach the handler to the DOM element after the DOM is ready...

Comment: I should have mentioned this, but in the actual project it's in the mobileinit event.  Also, sorry for not changing the title.  Once I realized that .blur() wasn't working, I made the sample, but forgot to change teh title of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Dave said, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search').blur(function() {
        alert('hello');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just use a non-jquery way of doing things?

```
document.getElementById("search").addEventListener('blur',function(){
    document.getElementById("search").value = "DEFAULT_VALUE";
});
```

Comment: BTW: this needs the DOM to be ready, so it's advised to put this in the window.onload or body.onload events. Like "<body onload="init();"> and in the script: